typeof array[number][key] not return const
When declaring the data type for CuisineTypeOptions, the Type does not function correctly. Is there a way for it to work properly?
// Code 1
const CuisineTypeOptions: { label: string; value: string }[] = [
  { label: 'Traditional', value: 'traditional' },
  { label: 'Typical', value: 'typical' },
] as const

type Type = (typeof CuisineTypeOptions)[number]['value'] // -> string

// Code 2
const CuisineTypeOptions = [
  { label: 'Traditional', value: 'traditional' },
  { label: 'Typical', value: 'typical' },
] as const

type Type = (typeof CuisineTypeOptions)[number]['value'] // -> 'traditional' | 'typical'


Change the code to be code 2? What are your constraints? Notice that if you declare the type of the objects to have value: string, then that's of course what you'll get.
